# can we execute multiple DML statements under elseif in MySql?

Tags: mysql

i am trying to execute 2 DMLs after ELSEIF  in Procedurelike below, but one statement is executing another one is not.

```
IF COUNT=0 THEN
INSERT INTO TABLE
SELECT * FROM TABLE;

ELSEIF (COUNT>0 and COUNT<0)

UPDATE TABLE
SET COL1=0 WHERE COL1=1; 

INSERT INTO TABLE
SELECT * FROM TABLE;
`INSERT INTO TABLE
SELECT * FROM TABLE`
```

here UPDATE is executing under ELSEIF but INSERT is not.
please let me know if any one have any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `COUNT>0 and COUNT<0` will **always** be evaluated as false

Comment: this is just example i have given as i am not supposed to show my project code.

Comment: can we execute 2 DMLs under elseif ?

Comment: i am pulling the updated  records from another table that is why i am comparing
ELSEIF target_count>0 and update_count>0 then
UPDATE T1 SET COL1=1;
INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT * FROM SOURCE
here Update is executing but INSERT is not.

Comment: can we execute 2 DMLs under elseif  - yes.

Comment: You may place any statements amount under ELSEIF **and until ENDIF;**.

Comment: Please don't publish code like INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT * FROM TABLE; it's very misleading and suggests you are trying to insert from same table..

Comment: thanks for suggession, but somehow 2nd DML is not executing at all. is there any way that we can rewrite the query?

Comment: As Akina said, if you do it correctly, you can place any number of statements in the elseif part. If it doesn't work for you, you did something wrong. Unfortunately, from your code sample, we cannot conclude anything. Even if you cannot share your original code (which is fine), a question about why your "if"-structure doesn't work should at least resemble your actual "if"-structure (e.g. it's `elseif ... THEN ...`, and `END IF` is missing too), so e.g. take your code and just replace the dml and conditions. Also, oftentimes, the problem is nested IFs, so make sure to include those if used.

Comment: Fine, you don't want to fix your syntactically incorrect code or provide code representative of your problem or sample data or expected outcome - best of luck I'm out.

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions, i have resolved the issue, there was a code issue as you said. its working fine. Thanks again!